# Reverse bitwise operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse-engineering

So I'm stuck

I recently bought a bluetooth device which interacts nicely with my phone, being me, I wanted to write a controller from the PC so started reverse engineering the BT traffic. (There is no SDK for this, the company that makes the device are explicit about this, I can live with it)

Now, the BT device emits 28 hexadecimal characters as "value" and decoding was easy enough (code below)

What I want to do now is reverse this procedure and encode my own, this is where I am failing.

As I said, the device emits 28 character hex string. Decoding this is simple as:

```py
import pandas as pd
from data import codes, lookup
pdcolumns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']

def mask(string):
    struct = {
        'a': None,
        'b': None,
        'c': None,
        'd': None
    }
    nibbles = [2,4,4,6]

    code = string[12:] # slice off the first 12 bits, these are an application ID and seemingly irrelevant
    offset = 0
    for i, key in zip(range(0, len(nibbles)), list(struct.keys())):
        current_byte = nibbles[i]
        partial = code[offset:(offset + current_byte)]
        struct[key] = int(partial, 16) & 0xFF
        if key == 'd':
            struct['h'] = int(partial, 16) # copy, no mask
        offset += current_byte
    struct['e'] = struct['d'] - (struct['d'] ^ ((struct['a'] * struct['c'])) & 0xFF)

    # breakdown columns
    struct['f'] = (struct['d'] ^ (struct['a'] * struct['c']))
    struct['g'] = struct['f'] & 0xFF
    return struct

transcribed = []
for code in codes:
    transcribed.append(mask(code))
df = pd.DataFrame(transcribed, columns=pdcolumns)
```

OK so the first 5 columns are easy:

1. sequence ID in range (1,126)
2. Controller
3. Parameter 1
4. Parameter 2 (value)
5. Result

Column h is the raw result from hex, unmasked
column f and g are breakdown columns from the equation that generates the result in `e`.

#### sample output

```
|      |   a |   b |   c |   d |   e |    f |   g |      h |
|-----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|-----:|----:|-------:|
|  924 |  21 |   1 |   0 |  51 |   0 |   51 |  51 | 589107 |
|  795 |  19 |   1 |   0 | 190 |   0 |  190 | 190 | 531646 |
|  491 | 111 |   3 |  48 | 249 | 208 | 5161 |  41 | 413945 |
| 1810 |  18 |   2 |   0 |  96 |   0 |   96 |  96 | 548960 |
| 1209 |  52 |   1 |   0 |  67 |   0 |   67 |  67 | 546115 |
| 1054 |  24 |   2 |   0 | 230 |   0 |  230 | 230 | 549606 |
| 1545 |   7 |   1 |   0 | 162 |   0 |  162 | 162 | 539042 |
|   68 |  69 |   3 |  34 | 238 |  42 | 2500 | 196 | 706542 |
|  242 | 116 |   3 |  76 | 220 |  48 | 8876 | 172 | 862684 |
| 1169 |  12 |   3 |  13 | 234 | 116 |  118 | 118 | 626410 |
```

#### sample input

```
243c08001812150101100008fd33
243c080018121301011000081cbe
243c080018126f010310300650f9
243c080018121201021000086060
243c080018123401011000085543
243c0800181218010210000862e6
243c0800181207010110000839a2
243c0800181245010310220ac7ee
243c08001812740103104c0d29dc
243c080018120c0103100d098eea
```

Given that there is binary masking going on, how can I reverse this equation? It's probably simple but I've been staring at this for too long now.

**Notes:**

Columns c & d are a modulo of 4096 therefore this is a valid replacement for 0
Column e might be (not shown) a negative number up to -256 - `df.sample` didn't pick any on this round

Any of d, g, h would be acceptable, especially if you can explain the steps

This isn't a homework project or work project, it's a side project where I'm hitting a brick wall and need to understand.

#### Clarify

I'm looking to reverse column `e` given only `e`, `a` and `c` to make `h` although I will accept any of `f`, `g` or `d` as these should be reversible

Comment: The only question I see is "Given that there is binary masking going on, how can I reverse this equation?" - what exactly do you mean? Can you give an example of an element of data you have and what you'd like to turn it into?

Comment: The clarification isn't really clear. You want to reverse `e` when `e` is given?

Comment: Isn’t the answer just some sort of `"%02x%04x…"%(code['a'],code['b'],…)`?